# Use Object Returned by readYaml from file in Declarative Jenkinsfile

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-groovy

I want to read the contents of a yaml file in a declarative Jenkinsfile via the readYaml utility. My understanding is that readYaml should return a Map, however, the object type I am seeing returned is a String. This defeats the purpose of putting the data in a yaml file in the first place.

Specifically, I want to get some values from a helm values.yaml file to set env values in the global environment section of the Jenkinsfile for all subsequent stages to be able to use.

The `println valuesYaml.getClass()` returns java.lang.String which I think is not correct because this object comes from a nested yaml file so I think the returned object should be a map.

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text

When the following echo statement runs `echo valuesYaml.appName.toString()` it errors out with the following error:

org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.lang.String appName

This is a snippet of the values.yaml I'm trying to read:

```
replicaCount: 1
appName: test
```

```
def loadValuesYaml(){
  def valuesYaml = readYaml (file: './chart/values.yaml')
  return valuesYaml;
}

pipeline {
  agent {
    label "jenkins-maven"
  }

  environment {
    valuesYaml = loadValuesYaml()
  }
  stages {
    stage('CICD Initialize') {
      steps {
        script{
          echo valuesYaml
          println valuesYaml.getClass()
        }
        echo valuesYaml.appName.toString()
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are setting your `valuesYaml` variable inside `environment` block, which makes it *string*. Move your variable declaration to `script` block, the variable will be accessible in subsequent stages.

```
def loadValuesYaml(){
  def valuesYaml = readYaml (file: './chart/values.yaml')
  return valuesYaml;
}

pipeline {
  agent {
    label "jenkins-maven"
  }
  stages {
    stage('CICD Initialize') {
      steps {
        script{
          valuesYaml = loadValuesYaml()
          println valuesYaml.getClass()
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        echo valuesYaml.appName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to declare them inside `environment` block, you can rewrite your `loadValuesYaml` function to return a specific string, however, this will call `readYaml` multiple times.

```
def loadValuesYaml(x){
  def valuesYaml = readYaml (file: './chart/values.yaml')
  return valuesYaml[x];
}

pipeline {
  agent {
    label "jenkins-maven"
  }
  environment {
    APP=loadValuesYaml('appName')
    REPLICACOUNT=loadValuesYaml('replicaCount')
  }
  stages {
    stage('CICD Initialize') {
      steps {
        script{
          println APP
          println REPLICACOUNT
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great!  Now, how to parse out the value in the "parameters" section of a template.yaml.  I am trying to use valueYaml.parameters["parameter-name"] and it fails with a RejectedAccessException.