# Jenkins / docker: Pull image from vendor repo and push to local repo

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to find a way to do the following for my `special-app` container provided by my vendor:

1. Pull docker image from vendor
2. Push the docker image into an internal repo (for a local copy)

Currently for other docker images I have from 3rd party repos I could find them in Github and they contain Dockerfile, which I then used in my pipeline to build and then pushed to my personal repo like so:

```
    stage('Clone from Git') {
        try {
            git branch: 'master',
                url: 'https://github.com/exampleapp.git'

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            println("Unable to git clone: ${ex}")
            error 'Git Clone failure'
        }
    }

    stage ('Build Docker Image') {
        try {
            dir('./') {
                def customImage = 
                 docker.build("myregistry.com/myimages/exampleapp:${env.BUILD_ID}")
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            error 'Docker Build failure'
        }
    }

    stage ('Push Image to Registry') {
        try {
            docker.withRegistry('https://myregistry.com', 'mycreds') {
                def customImage = 
                docker.image("myregistry.com/myimages/exampleapp:${env.BUILD_ID}")
                customImage.push('latest')
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            println("Unable push image to registry: ${ex}")
            error 'Registry Push failure'
        }
    }
```

But for `special-app`, the vendor basically only provides a yaml file, which I then used to create the container:

```
docker-compose -p special-app -f vendor-provided.yml up -d
```

While this works to have the container up and running, there is no Dockerfile provided with this method, so I'm not able to use the same methodology above that I'm using for other images that I do have Dockerfiles for.
What I should do in this case? How can I get the docker image from the vendor and push it to my local repo for safekeeping if I dont have a Dockerfile? Is there another way to achieve this in my pipeline?

(we keep local copies of these images as a standard process, even though we make no adjustments/customization to some of them - which is the case in this `special-app`).

Thanks
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to extract the url/name of the image that the vendor-provided.yml is pulling from and use it in a simple Dockerfile to pull the image and create your own:

Using the technique from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57261787/use-object-returned-by-readyaml-from-file-in-declarative-jenkinsfile) you can get the image value.

A new stage for your pipeline in which you create a single line Dockerfile:

```
stage('Make Dockerfile from vendor yaml') {
    steps {
        script{
            def valuesYaml = readYaml (file: './path-to/vendor-provided.yml')
            def line1 = "FROM ${valuesYaml.image}"
            writeFile file: "Dockerfile", text: line1
        }
    }
}
```

Creates Dockerfile:

```
FROM vendor-image
```

From here you should be able to build and push your image to your registry.

Comment: Sorry for the late upvote but spot on :) Thanks!